# Overriding routeKeyName to slug not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Here is my `show` method in my `PostController` and when I `dd($slug)` I get my slug from the database but when I try to search the post associated with that slug I get a `404 | Not Found`. I've override my `routeKeyName` in my model but it seems like it'still fetching using id column since when I replace `$slug` with a hard coded id of 2 in this line `$post = Post::findOrFail($slug);` then I get the post from the database. I can't figure out what it is that I'm missing.

```
 public function show($slug)
    {
        //dd($slug);
        $post = Post::findOrFail($slug);
        return view('single-blog', compact('post'));
    }
```

My Model `Post.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

   public function getRouteKeyName()
   {
       return 'slug';
   }
}
```

Comment: It should work. Try to use `request()->query('slug')` as alternative. Please make sure the post is within DB.

Comment: `use request()->query('slug')` where exactly? The post is there. When I query by `id` then `dd` I get the post object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even using a different database field, you're still using route model binding.
[From the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding):

> Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions whose type-hinted variable names match a route segment name.

So your route variable and the field you pass to your controller method need to match, and you need to type hint it:

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/posts/{post}', [PostController::class, 'show']);
```

**Controller:**

```
public function show(Post $post) {
```

Comment: If I got you correct, I must inject the entire model instance for it to work. It wouldn't work by querying my db using a passed in `$slug `?

Comment: `routeKeyName` is for use in your *routes*.  If you set it up as described here, Laravel does the work for you - it does the DB query, using your slug, transparently.  If you actually just want `findOrFail()` to work using a slug, then (as you guessed in your previous answer) you need to [tell Laravel to use a different primary key](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#primary-keys).  You then have to manually do (the same?) query Laravel would otherwise do for you with route model binding ... Your circumstances might be special but "the Laravel way" is probably easiest?

Comment: I deleted my answer, it didn't work as I thought so I thought it's misleading. I now think they do two different thing. Correct me if I'm mistaken. `routeKeyName` will query using the column provided in my case slug column but will not change id from being the primary key while protected `$primaryKey = 'slug';` will change the primary key to slug.

Comment: Right - though you would also need to update your DB, eg add a migration.

Answer (score 0):

Just add field after routeKeyName

```
Route::get('/post/{post:slug}', [PostController::class, 'show']);
```